# How can I make an Rspec test that goes green?

Tags: ruby, csv, rspec, tdd, automated-tests

I have a snippet of code below that as an argument takes in information from a row in a  CSV file and creates an Employee object. I am new to Rspec and can't seem to get my tests to pass even though I know my solution functions the way I want it to. I'd like to get a better understanding of Rspec in my efforts to learn test driven development. How can I write a test that shows that this code works? I realize this process is supposed to go the other way around (test first before creating the end product) but I'm doing it this way to try to learn how spec works better. If you need any more of my code please let me know:

CSV file:

```
first_name,last_name,annual_income,tax_paid,tax_rate
Johnny,Smith,120000,28000,38
Jane,Doe,140000,30000,40
Liz,Lemon,,21000,30
,Orsillio,40000,8800,18
Eric,Schmidt,54000,,28
```

Employee class:

```
class Employee
  attr_reader :last_name, :first_name, :annual_income, :tax_paid, :tax_rate

  def initialize(attributes) **#<-where the csv row is being passed in but in another main file used to run the code**

    @last_name = attributes['last_name'] ||="[Last Name]"
    @first_name = attributes['first_name'] ||="[First Name]"
    @annual_income = attributes['annual_income'].to_f ||= 0
    @tax_paid = attributes['tax_paid'].to_f ||= 0
    @tax_rate = attributes['tax_rate'].to_f ||= 0
  end
end
```

One of several Rspec test attempt:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'employee'

  describe Employee do
    it 'instantiated Employee class object should instantiate when missing arguments are passed in' do
      expect(Employee.new("").first_name).to eql("[First Name]")
    end
  end
```

This is the resulting output from the test:

```
F

Failures:

  1) Employee instantiated Employee class object should instantiate when missing arguments are passed in
     Failure/Error: expect(Employee.new("").first_name).to eql("[First Name]")
     IndexError:
       string not matched
     # ./employee.rb:9:in `[]='
     # ./employee.rb:9:in `initialize'
     # ./employee_spec.rb:6:in `new'
     # ./employee_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00029 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./employee_spec.rb:5 # Employee instantiated Em
```

Comment: Can you show the resulting output of the test?

Comment: @jamesw I just added the resulting output of the test

Comment: It looks like your test is working great! I just copied your class code and tried to run it from the rails console and indeed there is the same error in your class. So yur question should be, "How can I fix my class?" Haven't got a clue about that though

Comment: OK, Figured out your problem and added an answer. Please accept it if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error with your test, rather your test is oing it's job very nicely and telling you that you have a problem with your code.

You have

```
@last_name = attributes['last_name'] ||="[Last Name]"
```

Perhaps you should check to see if the attributes param holds the value you are looking for before trying to assign it? Same goes for all the attributes

The error is most likely because you are passing a string in as an argument instead of a hash yet you are trying to access the string as if it is a hash when you call `Employee.new("")`

So change your initialize method to this

```
  def initialize(attributes) #**#<-where the csv row is being passed in but in another main file used to run the code**
    if attributes.is_a? Hash
        @last_name = attributes['last_name'] ||="[Last Name]"
        @first_name = attributes['first_name'] ||="[First Name]"
        @annual_income = attributes['annual_income'].to_f ||= 0
        @tax_paid = attributes['tax_paid'].to_f ||= 0
        @tax_rate = attributes['tax_rate'].to_f ||= 0
    else
        @last_name = "[Last Name]"
        @first_name = "[First Name]"
        @annual_income = 0
        @tax_paid =  0
        @tax_rate =  0
    end
  end
```

Your test will pass and your class is fixed.

Tests rock! :)

Comment: Thanks, passed an empty hash instead of a string and it works